# Reading .ini file and adding all elements to array as a single element each

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to read an `.ini` file in Python. Then I want to write this file's elements to my list as a single element until the end of the data in the `.ini` file.

```py
f = open("b.ini", "r")
data = f.read()
ftp_data = [data]
print(ftp_data)
```

I am getting this result `['123456789abcdefghigklmnop123456789abcdefghigklmnop']`

I want to get `['1','2','3', 'N']`

Answer (score 0):

Using `list()` will convert a string into a list of its separate characters:

```
with open('b.ini') as f:
    data = list(f.read())
```